# Built a search link on Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate, dynamics-365

I have a power automate flow that updates a description field on a record and at this field I want a link of the search page. Depending on criteria during the flow, I want to built a link of the search page to search, for example, accounts named 'test'. So when user clicks on this link to be redirected to this search page. How this can be created?

Comment: Which search page you want to use? Dataverse search or the quick find view?

Comment: Any of them. Maybe I will create both of the links if it is possible, and business users will decide which fits them better